# Tweet : Getting error 32 Could not authenticate you

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, twitter-oauth

i want to post an tweet, i am getting access token from server , using that i am trying to tweet but getting error "Could not authenticate you", not able to find what wrong i am doing, here is my code which i am using for tweet.

private async Task TweetAsync
(string access_token1 = "", string oauth_verifier1 = "")
        {

```
        String TwitterUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

        string timeStamp = GetTimeStamp();
        string nonce = GetNonce();

        String SigBaseStringParams = "oauth_consumer_key=" + TwitterClientID.Text;
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + nonce;
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + timeStamp;
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_token=" + access_token1;
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_version=1.0";
        SigBaseStringParams += "&" + "status=twitteronwindowsphone";
        String SigBaseString = "POST&";
        SigBaseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(TwitterUrl) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(SigBaseStringParams);

        String Signature = GetSignature(SigBaseString, TwitterClientSecret.Text);

        HttpStringContent httpContent = new HttpStringContent("oauth_verifier=" + oauth_verifier1, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        string authorizationHeaderParams = "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + TwitterClientID.Text + "\", oauth_nonce=\"" + nonce + "\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_signature=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Signature) + "\", oauth_timestamp=\"" + timeStamp + "\", oauth_token=\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(access_token1) + "\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"";//, status=\"twitteronwindowsphone\"

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new HttpCredentialsHeaderValue("OAuth", authorizationHeaderParams);
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(TwitterUrl), httpContent);
        string response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        string abc = response;
    }
```

Comment: can anyone figure out the issue?

Comment: Can you post details of your GetSignature method?